# Sending images using server-set events

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to develop an application for classroom teaching. I have different clients for teachers and students. Clients log-in to the server. I want to transmit teacher's screen live to all the students. Can I accomplish this using server-set events in HTML-5. If not, how I can I accomplish this? I'm using Apache Web Server with PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe RTC (http://www.webrtc.org/) is a valuable technology to consider, however it is currently very sparsely supported.

Comment: Browser based window/screen sharing can be achieved through Adobe connect. Application based screen sharing can be achieved through a number of methods such as Skype, TeamViewer and Remote desktop sharing.

Comment: Screen sharing applications are pretty taxing on both clients and servers. Writing one from scratch is not an easy task. Why exactly do you want the screen sharing feature included into the teaching application?

Comment: @MihaiStancu I want to replace the whiteboard while teaching. I want to transmit his screen live to all the students. Can it be achieved using html5, javascript and php?